# Broken CSS keyframe animations when using WebPack's css-loader with UglifyJS plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, clean-css

We're using [este.js dev stack](https://github.com/steida/este) in our application which uses webpack to bundle JS & CSS assets. Webpack [is configured](https://github.com/steida/este/blob/f7e52c696a242bffc96b4f777ad9b03a031a3f54/webpack/makeconfig.js) to use `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` when building for production env and `stylus-loader`, well the exact loader configuration for production env. is as follows:

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
  'style-loader', 
  'css-loader!stylus-loader'
);
```

I then have 3 styl files:

```
// app/animations.styl
@keyframes arrowBounce
  0%
    transform translateY(-20px)
  50%
    transform translateY(-10px)
  100%
    transform translateY(-20px)

@keyframes fadeIn
  0%
    opacity 0
  50%
    opacity 0
  100%
    opacity 1

// components/component1.styl
@require '../app/animations'

.component1
  &.-animated
    animation arrowBounce 2.5s infinite

// components/component2.styl
@require '../app/animations'

.component2
  &.-visible
    animation fadeIn 2s
```

After the production build, both keyframe animations are renamed to `a` (probably some CSS minification by `css-clean`) and as you can deduce `fadeIn` overrides `arrowBounce` because of the same name and higher priority after minification.

Files `components/component1.styl` and `components/component2.styl` are being included in their React component file `[name].react.js` using statements:

```
import 'components/component1.styl'; 
import 'components/component2.styl';
```

I'm going nuts. Tried many different solutions but none really worked.

Comment: Seems that this is caused by the latest css-loader 0.15.1 which breaks a lot of things based on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues). Version 0.14.5 works correctly but produces duplicate keyframes when animations.styl is required multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out it was a [fresh new feature](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/89) of at that time the latest css-loader 0.15.1 but it didn't work correctly when using multiple separate CSS files. It can be [turned off](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/commit/e70901adac88a06d93712e6f41ddbe913cddd267) now as of 0.15.2.